# Draw to right margin using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I can draw up to the right edge of a page like this:

```
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]%
{%
    \draw (0,0)--(0,0-|current page.east);%
}%
```

How can I do something similar, but draw only up until the right *margin* of the page? That is, the edge at which text is wrapped.

I thought perhaps there would be a `current margin.east` or something like that, but that doesn't appear to be the case.

Comment: `tikzpagenodes`?

Comment: Are you by chance looking for `\draw (0,0)--(0,0-|current page text area.east)`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \draw (0,0)--(0,0-|current page marginpar area.east);%
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. TIL `tikzpagenodes`. It was `current page text area` that I was after.